# Java NIO: reading variable-sized blocks

Tags: java, buffer, nio

I would like to read a string from a TCP stream that is given with a byte length followed by the actual data. In Python, I would do

```
length = ord(stream.read(1))
data = stream.read(length)
```

How do I do the same in Java NIO? What I have is a buffer (of capacity 257)

```
stream.read(buffer); // cannot specify a size here
int length = buffer.get();
byte[] data = new byte[length];
buffer.get(data);
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work: the get() calls read *past* the data in the buffer :-(

I probably need some combination of flip, rewind, reset, etc., but I can't figure it out.

Comment: What sort of object is `stream` in your Java example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if `stream` is a `SocketChannel` and `buffer` is a `ByteBuffer`, you can do the following:

```
//assuming buffer is a ByteBuffer
buffer.position(0);
buffer.limit(1);
while (buffer.hasRemaining()) { 
   stream.read(buffer);
}
buffer.rewind();

//get the byte and cast it into the range 0-255
int length = buffer.get() & 0xFF;
buffer.clear();
buffer.limit(length);
while (buffer.hasRemaining()) { 
   stream.read(buffer);
}
buffer.rewind();
//the buffer is now ready for reading the data from
```

Comment: Thanks, that should work fine - although it looks fairly complicated.

Comment: its not that simple, one has to keep in mind that its not necessary to receive all the bytes at once or might have received multiple messages at once.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, you have a look into java.nio.channel.GatheringByteChannel and DatagramChannel. You'll need to specifiy a Datagram for your needs.

That's what you've done by your Python example (first byte indicates the payload length, read the playload using this length), which looks really fault-prone(!).

A datagram is a specification for a data stream. It divides your stream into packages, logically. So, a better strategy would be to send a payload-package first, that indicates the length of the payload (and the package size). Edit: Of course, both sides of the stream must speak the same protocol / datagram language.

Comment: I fail to understand your recommendation. GatheringByteChannel is an interface that is already implemented by SocketChannel which I'm already using - AFAIU, that's the standard channel to use for TCP. DatagramChannel is irrelevant, as that's for UDP, and I'm doing TCP. I also fail to see why having a protocol that first sends the length and then the payload is fault-prone - that's how HTTP 1.1 works, for example.

Comment: I missed some details with your problem. Thought, you've more a problem with allocation than with ByteBuffer's methods ;) 

Anyway, If your payload does not exceed 255 byte, Bkkbrad's solution is straight forward.